# Can I import one method from object.freeze

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6, react-redux

```
export default Object.freeze({
  fetchReseller: ({ offset, limit }) => ({
     type: FETCH_RESELLER,
     payload: { offset, limit },
  }),
// deleteReseller: ... etc
})
```

How do I import only one method, like `fetchReseller`, 
I don't need everything in this  Object.freeze.

> import { fetchReseller } from './actions/Reseller'

didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, because your exporting whole object.

Import syntax like

```
import { fetchReseller } from './actions/Reseller'
```

works in case of having named exports:

```
export const fetchReseller = ...
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Description

Answer (score 0):

```
export const fetchReseller = arg=> ({ type: "TYPE", payload:{arg}  });

export default Object.freeze({
    fetchReseller,
   // deleteReseller: ... etc
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that unless you refactor your code to the pattern @hsz suggested. If you don't want to refactor, you can use the destructuring technique:

```
import theWholeObject from './actions/Reseller';

const { fetchReseller } = theWholeObject;
```

Then you can use the `fetchReseller()` function.

**ADVANTAGE:**
Babel will extract that function out of that object and stores it in a const. If you are using webpack (specially webpack v4), a process called `TreeShaking (or uglify)` will remove the rest of the object from your module. Therefore the bundled file will ONLY have the fetchReseller function, and hence the file size won't increase at all.
You could import more than one by including more methods inside curly brackets comma separated.

```
const { fetchReseller, anotherMethod } = theWholeObject;
```

Keep in mind that the pattern that @hsz suggested is the industry standard. i.e. you should be exporting your actions one by one separately.

```
export const methodOne = () => {}

export const methodTwo = () => {}

export const methodThree = () => {}
```